# Can I inject a SessionBean into a Java EE AroundInvoke-Interceptor?

Tags: java, jboss, dependency-injection, jakarta-ee, interceptor

I have an EAR with modules:

- foo-api.jar
- foo-impl.jar
- interceptor.jar

In foo-api there is:

```
@Local
FooService // (interface of a local stateless session bean)
```

In foo-impl there is:

```
@Stateless
FooServiceImpl implements FooService //(implementation of the foo service)
```

In interceptor.jar I want

```
public class BazInterceptor {

  @EJB
  private FooService foo;

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept( final InvocationContext i) throws Exception {
    // do someting with foo service
    return i.proceed();
  }
```

The question is:

Will a Java EE 5 compliant application server (e.g. JBoss 5) inject into the interceptor?
If no, what is good strategy for accessing the session bean?

To consider:

- Deployment ordering / race conditions

Answer (score 7):

Yes, injection should occur in an interceptor, as mentioned for example in [An Introduction to the Java EE 5 Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/intro_ee5/) article (bold is mine):

> #### Easier Access to Resources Through Dependency Injection
>
> Dependency injection is a pattern in
>   which an object's dependencies are
>   supplied automatically by an entity
>   external to that object. The object is
>   not required to request these
>   resources explicitly, for example, by
>   looking them up in a naming service.
>   In the Java EE 5 platform, dependency
>   injection can be applied to all
>   resources that a component needs,
>   effectively hiding the creation and
>   lookup of resources from application
>   code. Dependency injection can be
>   applied throughout Java EE 5
>   technology -- in EJB software
>   containers, web containers, and
>   clients.
>
> To request injection of a resource, a
>   component uses the `@Resource`
>   annotation or, in the case of some
>   specialized resources, the `@EJB` and
>   `@WebServiceRef` annotations.
>   Following are some of the many
>   resources that can be injected:
>
> - `SessionContext` object
> - `DataSources` object
> - `UserTransaction`
> - `EntityManager` interface
> - `TimerService` interface
> - **Other enterprise beans**
> - Web services
> - Message queues and topics
> - Connection factories for resource adapters
> - Environment entries (for example, strings, integers, and so on)
>
> Resource injection can be requested by
>   any component class, that is, any
>   class whose life cycle is managed by
>   the container. In the EJB software
>   container, components that support
>   injection include the following:
>
> - EJB technology components
> - **Interceptors**
> - Message handlers for Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS) and Java API
>     for XML-based RPC (JAX-RPC)
>
> In web containers, components that
>   support injection are the following:
>
> - Servlets, servlet filters, event listeners
> - Tag handlers, tag library event listeners
> - Managed beans
>
> In the client container, the **main**
>   class and the `login` callback handler
>   components support injection.

See also the [EJB Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) section of the JBoss **EJB 3.0 Tutorial**:

> Just like a bean class, an interceptor
>   can be the target of Dependency
>   injection. The format for how this
>   works is the same, and the injection
>   works off the same ENC as the bean to
>   which the interceptor is bound.
>
> ...
>
> Remember that interceptors follow the
>   same lifecycle as the bean they are
>   bound to. The interceptors are created
>   at the same time as the bean instance
>   is created, and dependency injection
>   occurs before the first business
>   method is called.

#### Resources

- [An Introduction to the Java EE 5 Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/intro_ee5/)
- EJB 3.0 Tutorial

  - [EJB Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) (see the **Injection** section)

Answer (score -1):

My experience has indicated the injection can only occur in managed classes: EJB (Entity, Session or Message) and Servlets.